# How to merge issues with Bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

I have 2 issues that talk about the same problem in Bitbucket.

How do I merge them or close one to point it to the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way would be to close the duplicates, and cite the original issue.

> closing #4 as duplicate, see #2

'closing' and 'see' are keywords that automatically change '#4' and '#2' to links for those issues.

You can do this in a commit message or when you resolve the issue in the Issue Tracker.

More information here: [Available commands](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/resolve-issues-automatically-when-users-push-code-221451126.html)